# Using lubuntu on a PowerBook G4

Tags: linux, lubuntu, powerbook, g4

I've a Model: A1010 G4 laptop. Technically it seems to work very well, more reliable I think than my 13" 2011 model MacBook. I would like to use the G4 as an audio recorder for my digital piano. I have tried a few of the recommended Linux OS's but in most cases WiFi is inoperable, and in all cases screen lighting adjustment did not work at all. I currently have lubuntu on it. wifi is not recognised. any suggestions how to get wifi and screen brightness working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, what version of Lubuntu do you have running? I have a similar setup with Lubuntu 16.04 although my PB might be different.

Try launching a terminal and typing `lspci`

There should be something like Broadcom BXXXX

In my case, it was B43XX so I did `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`, at least, that's what I think it was.

Also for screen brightness, I've found I need to hold the Fn key and then press brightness up or down to adjust the brightness.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a go when I get back home, been travelling